# How do I save user entered text so that the user entered text reappears when page is reloaded?

Tags: html

I want to know how to save the user entered text inside a table?

I put a `<td> <input type="text" size="8"></td>`.

Is it possible to make the user type text into the text box and then reload the page with the user entered text still there?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible with raw HTML. You would need to use JavaScript to save the variable into `localStorage`, or make use of a back-end session variable like PHP's `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Okay! What is the javascript code? I use Visual studio Code

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with raw HTML. However, this **is** possible in two different ways - either store the data within the visitor's browser using JavaScript's `localStorage`, or store the data in a server-side database that outputs the variable to the page.

### **Storing the data within the visitor's browser:**

First, you want to ensure that you give your input field an `id`, to make it much easier to target with JavaScript. I'm going to give it the ID `variable`:

```
<td><input id="variable" type="text" size="8"></td>
```

Then you will need a 'trigger' mechanism to tell the JavaScript when to store what the user has entered into `localStorage`. I'm going to do that on key up (by calling a function called `remember`), so that whenever the user types something, the browser will remember it, without needing a button click or anything like that:

```
<td><input id="variable" type="text" size="8" onkeyup="remember()"></td>
```

Then we need to build a function to actually **store** the user input in `localStorage`:

```
function remember() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    localStorage.setItem('userinput', document.getElementById("variable").value);
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("variable").value = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage.";
  }
}
```

Finally, we need to build a second function that will get executed whenever the page is loaded, telling the browser to **load** the information from `localStorage`:

```
window.onload = function retrieve() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.userinput) {
      document.getElementById("variable").value = localStorage.userinput;
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle putting this all together, and demonstrating this functionality [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/4qvnrh24/) (hitting 'Run' is equivalent to refreshing).

For more information on storing data in `localStorage`, check out the W3School's page on [**HTML5 Web Storage**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

### **Storing the data on the server:**

To save the data into a **database**, you would need a back-end language like PHP to handle the actual insertion to the database. To send the data from the HTML to the back-end, you would (most commonly) want to make use of a **form**. Form elements need a **name** attribute to be interpreted by the back-end. In the following example, I'm using PHP, and calling the data your user enters `'variable'`:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="text" name="variable" size="8">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP (action_page.php):**

```
$data = $_POST['variable'];
```

PHP now houses whatever the user entered in a variable called `$data`, and is free to insert it into the database. **How** you insert the data depends on which approach you are using - MySQL, MySQLi, or PDO. Keep in mind that the MySQL extension of PHP is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), and [**removed as of PHP 7.0**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php), so I advise against using that.

For more information on sending data to the back-end, check out the W3School's pages on [**HTML Forms**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) and [**PHP Form Handling**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Hope this helps! :)